# Removing specific changes from old git commit

Tags: git

I committed multiple changes along with a large SQL database dump. Instead of fixing the issue right there, I continued by creating a new commit removing the large SQL dump.

`C1 (many changes and the SQL file) -> C2 (removed SQL file) -> C3 (more changes)`

How do I remove all references of the SQL file while preserving the rest of the history/changes?

Comment: If these commits are *unpublished* (i.e., only you have them), use `git rebase -i` to combine ("squash") C1 and C2.

Comment: Sounds like he wants to drop the extraneous commits, not squash them

Comment: @torek That works great - thank you.

Comment: He could select the "d" option in the interactive rebase to drop a commit, so seems like could go that way? no?

Comment: @DavidN Unfortunately, the commit with the offending SQL file has more changes than just the addition of the SQL file, so I can't just remove the entire commit.

Comment: What about spilling that commit up during the interactive rebase and then omitting the split out part that you don't want? See SPLITTING COMMITS under https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase.

Comment: @DavidN That definitely looks like the best solution. Thank you for that.